# In Ruby on Rails, how do I create a table/model that has a field in it that references the same table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to do this in Rails 3.  I create a table (syntax on code examples may not be exactly right, I am trying to recreate from memory):

```
create_table "persons", :force => true do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "guest_of_id"
end
```

And I want guest_id to reference another row in the persons table.  Each person is the guest of only one person.  So in the model I set up the association:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :GuestOf, :class => "Person", :foreign_key => "guest_of_id"
end
```

However, when I try to reference the guestOf field

```
a_person.GuestOf.name
```

I get the error

```
undefined method 'eq' for nil:NilClass
```

Is this possible in Rails?  Am I doing something wrong?  Am I missing a has_many relationship?  I strongly suspect my Google-Fu is failing me.  The only possible solution I have found is http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association but he is establishing a many to many relationship and I think it is more complicated than what I am trying to do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should be able to just do:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :host, :class => "Person", :foreign_key => "guest_of_id"
    has_one :guest, :class => "Person", :foreign_key => "guest_of_id"
end
```